# Is this correct usage: "My interests are closely aligned with that of Dr. XYZ"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

Is this correct usage:

> My interests are closely aligned with that of Dr. XYZ.

or does this sound better:

> My interests are closely aligned with the work of Dr. XYZ.

Comment: *My interests* is plural, so they would be closely aligned with ***those** of Dr. XYZ*. Apart from that it's really just a stylistic choice.

Comment: I don't see how your interests can be closely aligned with his work. His work can be closely aligned to your interests (that is, his work is consistent with your interests), but I don't see why you would actively align what you are interested in with his work. So the first, suitably corrected, is better, on the face of it. BUT we don't know what idea you are actually trying to convey.

Comment: @FumbleFingers it is entirely possible, even though highly unlikely, that Dr. XYZ has exactly one interest.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in FumbleFingers' comment, *interests* is plural, which calls for the plural *those* instead of singular *that*.  Alternately, one might say (correctly, but a bit clumsily) “My interest is closely aligned with that of Dr. XYZ”.

As intimated by Andrew Leach's comment, “interests are aligned with work” is semantically questionable, but you could say your interests are consistent with the work, or vice versa.  You could also say Dr. XYZ's work entails issues with which your interests align, but that is perhaps roundabout.